# Python is throwing TypeError: add_nodes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nodelist'

Tags: python

Can someone please help me fix this error: TypeError: add_nodes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nodelist'I am still learning. I am not even what the error means other than that I am missing a request somewhere.

Any help and explanation of what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

### Here are my models:

```
class Graph(object):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.node_neighbors = {}
        self.visited = {}

    def add_nodes(self,nodelist):
        for node in nodelist:
            self.add_node(node)

    def add_node(self,node):
        if node not in self.add_nodes():
            self.node_neighbors[node] = []

    def add_edge(self,edge):
        u, v = edge
        if(v not in self.node_neighbors[u]) and (u not in self.node_neighbors[v]):
            self.node_neighbors[u].append(u)
            if(u!=v):
                self.node_neighbors[v].append(u)

    def nodes(self):
        return self.node_neighbors.keys()

    def depth_first_search(self, root=None):
        order = []
        def dfs(node):
            self.visited[node] = True
            order.append(node)
            for  n in self.node_neighbors[node]:
                if not n in self.visited:
                    dfs(n)
        if root:
            dfs(root)
        for node in self.nodes():
            if not node in self.visited:
                dfs(node)
        print(order)
        return order

    def breadtg_frist_search(self, root = None):
        queue = []
        order = []
        def bfs():
            while len(queue) >  0:
                node = queue.pop()
                self.visited[node] = True
                for n in self.node_neighbors[node]:
                    if (not n in self.visited) and (not n in queue):
                        queue.append(n)
                        order.append(n)
        if root:
            queue.append(root)
            order.append(root)
            bfs()
        for node in self.nodes():
            if not node in self.visited:
                queue.append(node)
                order.append(node)
                bfs()
        print(order)
        return order

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = Graph()
g.add_nodes([i+1 for i in range(10)])
g.add_edge((1, 2))
g.add_edge((1, 3))
g.add_edge((2, 4))
g.add_edge((2, 5))
g.add_edge((4, 8))
g.add_edge((5, 8))
g.add_edge((5, 9))
g.add_edge((3, 6))
g.add_edge((3, 7))
g.add_edge((7, 10))
g.add_edge((9, 10))
print('nodes:' + g.nodes())
order = g.breadtg_frist_search(1)
order = g.depth_first_search(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at line 12, where the error is coming from.

```
def add_node(self,node):
    if node not in self.add_nodes():
        self.node_neighbors[node] = []
```

You're calling `self.add_nodes()` with no arguments, but what you want to do is

```
def add_node(self,node):
    if node not in self.nodes():
        self.node_neighbors[node] = []
```

Additionally, you're trying to concatenate a string to dict keys. If you want to just print the keys, switch

```
print('nodes:' + g.nodes())
```

for

```
print('nodes:', g.nodes())
```

Comment: So appreciate !!

Comment: @awc789 great! If it has worked for you, please don't forget to accept the answer in order to mark the question as solved.